# GET Month, Quarter based on Work Week number

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to get month and quarter based on workweek number.

Ex: If Workweek number is 7 then it falls in Quarter=1 and Month = 2.

Similarly if WK = 35 I should be able to get quarter= 2 and Month = 8

and so on.

Comment: ISO weeks or something else? What is the month / quarter in cases  it changes in the middle of the week?

Comment: and what about the year? say if you pass 7 work week what year's quarter and Month you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a function to handle this .....

### Function Definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_Quater_Month (@WeekofYear INT)
RETURNS Table 
AS
RETURN
(WITH X AS
 (
  SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) % 4 = 0 THEN 366 ELSE 365 END) 
      DATEADD(DAY 
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
             , CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' )      
                      DayNumber
  From master..spt_values
 )
SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER,MIN(DayNumber)) AS [QUARTER]
      ,DATEPART(MONTH,MIN(DayNumber))   AS [Month]
FROM X 
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK,DayNumber) = @WeekofYear)
```

### Test

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.get_Quater_Month (7)
```

### Result

```
╔═════════╦═══════╗
║ QUARTER ║ Month ║
╠═════════╬═══════╣
║    1    ║   2   ║
╚═════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: May I ask why function and not sp?

Comment: well an sp would be better, but considering this is an inline table function, performance shouldn't be an issue.