# Creating a date from Week of month and Day of week in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have to get/create date from the user input of **week of month** (week number in that month - 1st,2nd,3rd,4th and last) and **day of week** (sunday,monday..) in SQL server.

Examples: 
4th Sunday of every month, Last Friday of every month, First Monday etc.

I was able to do it easily in .net but SQL server does seem limited in the date functions.

I am having to use lot of logic to get the date. To calculate the date using the above two parameters I had to use lot of datepart function.

Any suggestions on how to come up with the optimal SQL query for such a function?

Comment: If you are using sql server 2012 and above, have a look at `DATEFROMPARTS()` function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213228.aspx

Comment: Have you considered making a [CLR Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) using the .NET code you already have?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - Yes, I did read consider it but it takes year, month and date as parameters. What is I need is something similar to DateFromParts but more of a drilled down version of it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function other day for another OP [`GET Month, Quarter based on Work Week number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32285975/get-month-quarter-based-on-work-week-number/32286651#32286651)

This function takes the current year as default it can be further modified to take Year as a parameter too.

an extension to that function can produce the results you are looking for ....

```
WITH X AS
(
SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) % 4 = 0 THEN 366 ELSE 365 END)-- to handle leap year 
      DATEADD(DAY 
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
             , CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' )      
                      DayNumber
  From master..spt_values
 ),DatesData AS(
SELECT DayNumber [Date]
      ,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DayNumber) DayOfTheWeek
      ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, 
            DATEADD(WEEK, 
               DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 
                           DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DayNumber), 0)), 0)
              , DayNumber- 1) + 1 WeekOfTheMonth
FROM X )
SELECT * FROM DatesData
WHERE DayOfTheWeek   = 6  -- A function would expect these two parameters
 AND  WeekOfTheMonth = 4  -- @DayOfTheWeek and @WeekOfTheMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general formula:

```
declare @month as datetime --set to the first day of the month you wish to use
declare @week as int  --1st, 2nd, 3rd...
declare @day as int   --Day of the week (1=sunday, 2=monday...)

--Second monday in August 2015
set @month = '8/1/2015'
set @week = 2
set @day = 2

select dateadd(
    day,
    ((7+@day) - datepart(weekday, @month)) % 7 + 7 * (@week-1),
    @month
    )
```

You can also find the last, 2nd to last... etc with this reverse formula:

```
--Second to last monday in August 2015
set @month = '8/1/2015'
set @week = 2
set @day = 2

select
    dateadd(
    day,
    -((7+datepart(weekday, dateadd(month,1,@month)-1)-@day)) % 7 - 7 * (@week-1),
    dateadd(month,1,@month)-1
    )
```

Comment: I tried this myself and it worked beautifully (both cases). It's a solution easy to understand and very reusable. Most of American holidays are based on the number of the week of the month, so this function comes very convenient.